# Why doesn't the black bishop just capture the white knight?

Tags: analysis, positional-play

In a [game](http://it.lichess.org/xTbJYOfO/black#13) of mine, the below position emerged.

```
[FEN "r1bqkb1r/2pp1ppp/p1p2n2/4N3/4P3/2N5/PPPP1PPP/R1BQK2R b KQkq - 0 1"]
```

It is Black to move. The computer suggests the move 6... Bd4, and then it suggests 7. O-O for White. Why doesn't the black bishop just take the white knight on e5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Black could take the knight on e5, but then after d4 the bishop doesn't have any good squares. If he tries to retreat to d6, knight and bishop will be forked with e5. In the end white will have better development and better central control, it definitely looks like a ready-made attacking position for white.

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 a6 4.Bxc6 bxc6 5.Nxe5 Nf6 6.Nc3 Bc5 7.a3 Bd4 
8.O-O Bxe5 9.d4 Bd6 10.e5
```

Comment: Thanks. I definitely have a problem to see pawn forks. Also later in the game I get a fork by a pawn.... I'm much more trained to see knight forks than pawn's.